# C++ Class parameter what is this?

Tags: c++

When I study about "Class Template Partial Specialization", I read the below code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class stream
{
  public:
   void f() {   cout << endl << "stream<typename T1, typename T2>::f()";  }
};

template <typename T1>
class stream<T1, int>
{
  public:
   void f() { cout << endl << "stream<typename T1, int>::f()"; }
};

int main()
{
   stream<char, float> si ;
   stream<double, int> sc ;
   si.f();
   sc.f();    
   cout << endl;
   return 0 ;
}
```

In the above code, I cant able to understand the line

```
class stream<T1, int>
```

Whether these two parameters ***T1, int*** are parameters to constructors of that class or something else ?
If we specify some list with <..., ...> during class declaration then what is this? how to understand this ?

Answer (score 3):

That's the "partial" in "Class Template Partial Specialization", you're specifying some, but not all, template parameters.  In your `main`, `stream<double, int>` matches the partial specialization because it's second argument is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The first template is taking 2 generic arguments, the second will be called when a generic argument and an int are specified. This means you are providing a different implementation, for say performance when a particular set of types are sent in.

Comment: Yeh, I understood, when we call "stream<double, int> sc;" this line the second template definition will be called. Actually my doubt is the line (second template definition) "class stream<T1, int>" is necessary ? instead we can specify it in the above line "template <typename T1, int> like this, why we have to specify it in the next line, I mean i the class declaration ?

Comment: it is so you can provide 2 implementations, a really generic one (the 1st) and a more optimised one for the second. Any call with int as the second parameter will go to the optimised implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you partially specialize a template, you have to pass arguments. This is just what the line does. `stream` is a class-template taking two arguments. The partial specialization fixed the second argument to `int`, while leaving the first one variable. Hence the specialization has one less argument (only `T1`). You have to tell the compiler which of the arguments is fixed, so you have to pass type arguments to the template. This is done in the line `class stream<T1, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

See the following quote from Wikipedia

> If one knows that a class template will be used with a specific data type fairly often and this data type allows some optimizations (e.g. bit shifting with integers, as opposed to multiplying or dividing by 2), one may specialize the template by specifying another class template that is identical but by specifying the parameter types. When the compiler sees such a class template instantiated in code, it will generally choose the most specialized template definition that matches the instantiation. Therefore, an explicit specialization (one where all the template arguments are specified) will be preferred to a partial specialization if all the template arguments match.

So, it is for helping the compiler to optimize the template.